# Test for all true bits being adjacent

Tags: assembly, optimization, bit-manipulation, x86-64, masm

I am building a Huffman prefix code LUT by traversing the tree. I am using a register to keep track of the current prefix.

My condition for exiting the algorithm which parses the tree uses the following conditions, which must be true:

1. current element in tree must be a leaf
2. the current prefix code has all bits set without false bits.

For the second condition, I am also keeping track of he current length (in bits) of the prefix string.

How can I test that a register has more than 1 bit set and that all set bits are adjacent to each other?

EDIT: The group of set bits must start at bit 0 and be as long as prefix length (stored in another register)

Comment: Can you assume BMI1 (and BMI2)?  My first idea is that adding 1 to the low bit of a contiguous group will clear all the bits with carry-out.  (0xff + 1 = 0x100), so you want to add the lowest set bit and see if the result has exactly 1 bit set (i.e. test if it's a power of 2 with `x & (x-1) == 0`  https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2).  BMI1 `blsi` = isolate lowest set bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes I like that idea, I have implemented it with a `inc` on the prefix and then used `bt prefix, prefix length`, ends up with CF set if it was all contiguous set bits. Thanks! EDIT: Ahh I see why I need power of two now..

Comment: This method won't work for cases where the prefix starts with a 0 (high bit zero). I have the length in a different register and with a legnth 3, prefix code 001, it evaluates succeeds in the check, where it should fail.

Comment: Oh, your contiguous bits are guaranteed to be at the bottom of the register?  That's easier than the general case of the title and final questions!  Saves you a `blsi` or `(-x) & x`  to isolate the lowest-set.  And that + knowing the current prefix length enables `bt`, yeah that's very good, much easier than I was coming up with to distinguish between 1 bit set vs. multiple bits set.  (e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/LaOW27  `blsi` / `add` / `blsr` sets ZF if the input had only 1 or 0 contiguous bit-group, but didn't rule out it being only 1 bit long.)

Comment: xD, so that's *not* guaranteed after all.  What does "succeed" or "fail" mean in your terminology?  `0b001` has only 1 bit set (not multiple), so it shouldn't meet the criterion you're trying to detect.  You're getting a false positive from `inc`/`bt`?  How?  `0b001 + 1 = 0b010`, not `0b1000` which `bt reg, 3` would look for.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah the set bits must be together and start at bit 0. I don't understand the ´blsi´ instruction. So I need to test for a single set of grouped bits, bit0 and bit(prefixlength-1)?

Comment: What does "succeed" or "fail" mean in your terminology?  `0b001` has only 1 bit set (not multiple), so it shouldn't meet the criterion you're trying to detect. You're getting a false positive from `inc`/`bt`?  How?  `0b001 + 1 = 0b010`, not `0b1000` which `bt reg, 3` would look for. You'd have a problem with inputs like `0b011`, though, which has 2 bits set and thus *does* meet your condition, but `0b100 & (1<<3)` is false, so `bt` would be testing the wrong bit. Can you edit your question with more details on what assumptions you can/can't make, and maybe some test cases with required result?

Comment: @PeterCordes a sucess is testing for a single group of set bits where the number of set bits matches a value in another register. The group of bits must also start at bit0 as you said. ´inc/bt´ failed because it wasn't taking into account sequences of bits starting with 0 (´001´).

Comment: You need to update the title and more of the question to actually ask what you really need, not just a PS at the bottom with the real question.  Some test-cases would really help.  Your edit says the bit-group must be as long as the prefix length, but if that's the case then `inc`/`bt` *should* work (except for the length=1 special case where that's not multiple bits).  It sounds like you're asking how to check that all bits from 0 to len-1 are set, i.e. that `x == (1<<len) - 1`.   Is that not the case?

Answer (score 2):

The building block for this is going to be: **adding 1 to the low bit of a contiguous group will clear all those bits with carry-out, leaving 1 bit set above the group. e.g. 0xff + 1 = 0x100**.

If any bits are unset, carry won't propagate all the way up, e.g. `0b01101 + 1 = 0b01110`, not setting bit #4.  (And leaving some of the existing set bits un-flipped, so `x & (x+1)` will be true.)

This works for bit-groups at the bottom of a register (adding 1), or at any higher position (isolate the lowest set bit with `(-x) & x` and add that, e.g. with  [BMI1 `blsi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi) or mov/neg/and).

A related bithack is the `y & (y-1)` test for an integer having only a single bit set (by clearing the lowest set bit): https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2.  But since we're producing `y` with `x+1`, we can optimize it down to just `x & (x+1)` to detect a contiguous mask at the bottom of a register.

---

#### Your specific case is very easy:

- bottom of the bit-range must be bit 0
- bit-range is exactly `n` bits wide (the prefix-length)

Those restrictions mean **there's exactly 1 integer that matches both requirements**, so you should **pre-compute it and simply compare for equality with `cmp/je`**.   The number with `n` bits set at the bottom is `prefix_mask = (1<<n) - 1`.  Carry (borrow) by the subtraction sets all the bits below that isolated high bit, and clears the original bit.  Bits above that stay unset, because that high bit satisfied the borrow.

**Given the prefix-length `n`, you can compute `1<<n` using `bts` (which is single-uop on Intel CPUs, or 2 uops on AMD, https://agner.org/optimize/)**.

```
;; input: prefix length in EDX
;; output: prefix mask in ESI
xor    esi, esi
bts    esi, edx         ; set bit n;  eax |= 1<<n
dec    esi              ; set all the bits BELOW that power of 2

 ; then later, inside a loop: input in EAX
  cmp   eax, esi
  je    all_bits_set_up_to_prefix
```

@fuz proposed a LUT for this but that sounds like a bad idea even if you have to consider different prefix lengths very frequently.  If you're short on registers, you can spill it to stack memory after computing and use something like `cmp [rsp+16], edx` instead a static LUT while looping with the same prefix length.

Or spill the prefix length to memory if you don't need it in a register for a while, and just keep the mask.

You can even translate a mask back to a prefix length with `lea edx, [eax+1]` / `bsr edx,edx` to find the bit-index of the highest set bit of `mask+1`.  (Or if a prefix-length of 32 is possible but zero isn't, then `bsr` / `inc`.  [BSR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsr) with input=0 leaves the destination unmodified, and sets ZF.  AMD documents this, Intel's docs say "undefined" but their current HW does leave the destination unmodified, which is why the instruction has a "false" dependency on the output.)

---

#### Or without pre-computing

Non-destructive test of EDX for the low `n` bits all-ones, and bit #n itself being 0.  (Adding 1 clears the low bits and sets bit `n` *if* that was the case).  You can use `inc edx` instead of LEA to copy-and-add, if you don't have a use for it after.

```
;;; check the low n bits, ignoring whether higher bits are set or not
;;; inputs: prefix length in ECX, candidate in EDX
    lea  eax, [rdx+1]             
    bt   eax, ecx
;;; output: CF = 1 if all the bits from 0..len-1 were set, else 0
```

**If you also want to rule out any higher bits being set** you need one more instruction, but it can be a `test` instruction that will macro-fuse with a `jcc`, so on Intel CPUs this doesn't cost any extra uops.  On AMD CPUs, where `btr` is 2 uops vs. `bt` being 1, this costs 1 extra uop.  (test/jcc can fuse on AMD Bulldozer-family and later.)

```
;;; input: prefix length in ECX, candidate in EDX
   lea     eax, [rdx+1]      ; produces a single set bit?
   btr     eax, ecx          ; reset that bit, leaving eax=0 if no other bits were set
   test    eax, eax          ; compare against zero
;;; output: ZF=1 (and eax=0) if EDX == (1<<ECX)-1 with no higher bits set.

   jz     contiguous_bitmask_of_length_ecx
```

**This costs 3 uops total on Intel (4 on AMD), including the macro-fused test/jz, to branch on this condition**.  And it doesn't destroy the input register.

---

**We can check for a single contiguous bit-group of unknown length at the bottom of a register with `x & (x+1)`**, which does detect if any higher bits were set.  If there's a high bit that isn't flipped by carry-propagation, the AND or TEST will produce a non-zero result.

But this treats `0` and `1` the same as multi-bit groups like `0b0111`.  You might want `cmp eax, 3` / `jb not_multibit_prefix` before this test.

```
; check for a contiguous bit-group at the bottom of a reg of arbitrary length, including 0
;;; input: candidate in EDX
   lea   eax, [rdx+1]              ; carry-out clears all the set bits at the bottom
   test  eax, edx                  ; set flags from x & (x+1)
;;; output: ZF=1 if the only set bits in EDX were a contiguous group at the bottom
```

I looked at a weird partial-flags hack of `lea eax, [rdx+1]` / `test eax, edx` (ZF=1: only contiguous low bits were set) / `bt  eax, ecx` (CF=1: it ended at the position we want).  But x86 doesn't have a [`jcc` condition](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) that requires CF=1 *and* ZF=1.  `ja` is taken if `(CF=0 and ZF=0)`, `jbe` is taken if `(CF=1 or ZF=1)`, so neither works.  And of course this would be horrible on CPUs without efficient partial-flag merging, causing a partial-flag stall.

---

### The general case: bitgroup doesn't have to start at the bottom.

This rules out simple pre-computing.

As mentioned above, **we can isolate the lowest set bit with `(-x) & x`.  BMI1 added an instruction for that, `blsi`**.  So if you can assume BMI1 support, you can do this non-destructively in 1 uop.  Otherwise it takes 3.

```
unsigned bits_contiguous(unsigned x) {
    unsigned lowest_set = (-x) & x;  // isolate lowest set bit
    unsigned add = x + lowest_set;   // carry flips all the contiguous set bits
    return (add & x) == 0;           // did add+carry leave any bits un-flipped?
}
```

I put this on the Godbolt compiler explorer to see if gcc or clang spotted any optimizations I didn't think of.  Of course you don't actually want to materialize a 0 / 1 integer like we're asking the compiler to do, but since they choose to use `test` / `setcc` we can just look at what they do to create the right flag condition.

We can write some test functions to make sure the logic is correct for some compile-time constants with `#define TEST(n) int test##n(){return bits_contiguous(n);}` (and see if the asm is `xor eax,eax` or `mov eax,1`).  **See [C + asm on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'/*%0Aunsigned+bits_contiguous_old(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++unsigned+lowest_set+%3D+(-x)+%26+x%3B++//+isolate+lowest+set+bit%0A++++unsigned+add+%3D+x+%2B+lowest_set%3B+++//+carry+flips+all+the+contiguous+set+bits%0A++++return+(add+%26+(add-1))+%3D%3D+0%3B+++++//+single+bit+set%3F++(or+zero)%0A%7D%0A//+compilers+don!'t+realize+that+add-1+can+be+add-lowest_set+%3D+x+without+loss+of+correctness%0A*/%0A%0Aunsigned+bits_contiguous(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++unsigned+lowest_set+%3D+(-x)+%26+x%3B++//+isolate+lowest+set+bit%0A++++unsigned+add+%3D+x+%2B+lowest_set%3B+++//+carry+flips+all+the+contiguous+set+bits%0A++++return+(add+%26+x)+%3D%3D+0%3B+++++++++++//+did+add%2Bcarry+leave+any+bits+un-flipped%3F%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23define+TEST(n)+int+test%23%23n()%7Breturn+bits_contiguous(n)%3B%7D%0ATEST(0xf0)%0ATEST(0x10f0)%0ATEST(0x2f0)%0ATEST(0b00101000)%0ATEST(0b10101000)%0ATEST(0)+++++++++++//+special+case:+no+bits+at+all+doesn!'t+fail+the+test%0ATEST(1)%0ATEST(2)%0ATEST(3)%0ATEST(5)%0ATEST(0x80000000)%0ATEST(0xc0000000)%0ATEST(0xFFFFFFFF)+++//+works+even+when+add+clears+*all*+the+bits%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.37231010042743,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3++-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:28.262974697076164,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3++-Wall+-march%3Dsandybridge',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:26.364715202496424,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).**  Some interesting cases are `TEST(0)` = 1, because the condition basically checks for there being multiple bit-groups.  (So zero bit groups is the same as 1 bit-group, for this check.)  `TEST(0xFFFFFFFF)` = 1 as well: having `x+1 = 0` isn't a problem.

With gcc8.3 -O3, we get

```
# gcc8.3 -O3 -march=haswell  (enables BMI1 and BMI2)
bits_contiguous:
    blsi    eax, edi
    add     eax, edi
    test    eax, edi         # x & (x+lowest_set)

    sete    al
    movzx   eax, al
    ret
```

Without BMI1, we need 3 instructions instead of 1 for `blsi`:

```
    mov     eax, edi
    neg     eax
    and     eax, edi         # eax = isolate_lowest(x)
    add     eax, edi
    test    eax, edi
```

To also check for a specific *length* of the bit-group, @fuz had a good idea:  `popcnt` to make sure the right number of bits were set (and separately check that they're contiguous).  **Popcnt is not baseline, CPUs before Nehalem don't have it and will fault if they try to run it.**

```
;input: prefix len in ECX, candidate in EDX
;clobbers: EAX
    popcnt  eax, edx
    cmp     eax, ecx
    jne     wrong_number_of_bits_set  ; skip the contiguousness test

    blsi    eax, edi
    add     eax, edi
    test    eax, edi         # x & (x+lowest_set)
    jz     contiguous_bitgroup_of_length_ecx

wrong_number_of_bits_set:
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your number be in `eax` and the desired prefix length be in `edx`.

First of all, to get the number of trailing ones, compute the complement and the compute the number of trailing zeroes (we branch to `fail` if the number does not match).  The `cmovz` is needed as `bsf` doesn't like being invoked with 0 as its argument.  If this case doesn't appear, you can remove the first three instructions.

```
       mov ebx, 32      ; number of bits in an int

       mov ecx, eax
       not ecx
       bsf ecx, ecx     ; count trailing zeroes in ecx
                        ; i.e. trailing ones in eax
       cmovz ecx, ebx   ; give correct result for eax == -1
       cmp ecx, edx
       jnz fail         ; have as many ones as desired?
```

If your CPU has `tzcnt`, you can avoid this instruction:

```
        mov ecx, eax
        not ecx
        tzcnt ecx, ecx
        cmp ecx, edx
        jnz fail
```

Note that on CPUs that do not have it, `tzcnt` is silently interpreted as `bsf`, breaking your code; watching for an undefined instruction exception is insufficient to make sure it's present.

To make sure that no other bits are set, clear out the suffix and check if the result is zero:

```
        lea ecx, [rax+1]
        and ecx, eax      ; ecx = eax & eax + 1
                          ; i.e. clear all trailing 1 bits
        jnz fail          ; fail if any bits are left
```

Though the fastest implementation would probably just to make a look up table with all suffix lengths and then check if your suffix matches:

```
lut:    dd 00000000h, 00000001h, 00000003h, 00000007h
        dd 0000000fh, 0000001fh, 0000003fh, 0000007fh
        dd 000000ffh, 000001ffh, 000003ffh, 000007ffh
        dd 00000fffh, 00001fffh, 00003fffh, 00007fffh
        dd 0000ffffh, 0001ffffh, 0003ffffh, 0007ffffh
        dd 000fffffh, 001fffffh, 003fffffh, 007fffffh
        dd 00ffffffh, 01ffffffh, 03ffffffh, 07ffffffh
        dd 0fffffffh, 1fffffffh, 3fffffffh, 7fffffffh
        dd ffffffffh

        ...

        cmp lut[edx * 4], eax
        jnz fail
```

Comment: I have added edit to question, I didn't explain very well.

Comment: @Will I have amended my answer to address this.

Comment: @Will If you like, I can also cast my answer in x86 assembly.

Comment: @Will: let a compiler do it for you, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ compile with clang or `gcc -O3`.

Comment: BSF sets ZF if its *input* was zero.  If you need to branch for that, it might be best to `jz special_case` after `bsf` especially if you expect that to be rare.

Comment: @PeterCordes I thought about this, but given that `bsf` performs a partial flag update, evaluating its flags afterwards seems like a bad idea.  It is also possible to use `xor -1, ecx` instead of `not` and branch on the result to save an instruction, but since `cmp` is micro-fused with `jz`, there should be little difference.

Comment: On paper, BSF leaves the other flags *undefined*, not *unmodified*.   In real hardware, are there any flags it preserves?  I don't recall reading or noticing a flag false dependency (only on the output register, which is left unmodified for input=0).   In any case, `jz` only reads flags that were written by `bsf`, so it's fine.  Just like `dec / jnz` is fine and doesn't cause partial-flag stalls even though dec leaves CF unmodified.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, I misread the instruction set manual.  That is a good point.  Let me amend the code to fix that.

Comment: BTW, if this NOT / BSF / CMP works then I think the OP's `inc eax / bt eax, edx` should work, unless there can be other set bits at even higher positions outside the known prefix length.  Maybe I'm having a brain fart, but I don't think their comments under the question make sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes An even easier method would be to set up a register containing the desired suffix (i.e. by means of a LUT or variable shift and then decrement) and simply compare.

Comment: Oh good point, yes `xor`-zero a reg, then `bts edx, len` / `dec edx` to create `(1<<len) - 1`.  BTS is an often-overlooked instruction for creating `1<<n` efficiently, especially on Intel CPUs where it's single-uop vs. 2 on AMD.

Comment: I came up with a trick that uses `+1` and `btr` / `test` on a candidate to branch on this condition in only 3 uops, with no LUT or pre-computation.  Posted an answer I'd been working on.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see.  I know exactly what you mean.